# How to create a clickable button with Firefox Add-on Builder

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

can someone provide me an code-example for a simple extension:

- Clickable Button
- When a user clicks on this button it opens a new tab with some example-page

  [image]

Googling didn't help me..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a github repo I created that uses Erik Vold's toolbar button library to do this:

https://github.com/canuckistani/toolbar-template

Once the Firefox UI refresh project 'Australis' lands in Firefox 27 or 28, there will be built-in apis to allow you to do this, but this should get you started for now.

Comment: if you supplied link to the code you;re using or the Add-on Builder project it would make it easier for people to help you.